# What's the word for people who pretend and are disguised as a fictional character?

Tags: word-request

What's the word for people who pretend and are disguised as a fictional character? For example, there are people who disguise themselves as Spider Man or Han Solo, what do we call these people? I am looking for the noun.

For example:

> The kid saw a Han Solo ____ at the new Star Wars theme park in Disney
>   world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in Disney they are called [Characters](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Theme_Park_Characters/Atmosphere_Characters).

I would also say that the article "the" would be used if you are referring to the only/official one that would be at a Disney Park. But if you were at a comic con and a fan was dressing up as a character, they would be described as "a cosplay Han Solo" (short for costume play) since there are likely many people dressed as Han Solo there.

Answer (score 2):

One common word is [**impersonator**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impersonate):

> [Merriam-Webster, from *impersonate*]
>
> : to assume or act the character of : PERSONATE

---

A more recent term is [**cosplayer**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosplay):

> [Wikipedia, from *cosplay*]
>
> **Cosplay** (コスプレ kosupure), a portmanteau of the words **costume play**, is a performance art in which participants called **cosplayers** wear costumes and fashion accessories to represent a specific character.

---

So:

> The kid saw a Han Solo *impersonator* at the new Star Wars theme park in Disney world.
>   The kid saw a Han Solo *cosplayer* at the new Star Wars theme park in Disney world.

I get the impression that an *impersonator* more generally impersonates a real person than a fictional character, but the dictionary definition doesn't support that, and it may just be how I've come to use that word myself.